# CSS- How to dispose div in a single row in a grid?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a particular issue. I'm working with Angular and I'm developing a gantt timeline and I have a div container with this css:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 15px 12px 0 0;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 1fr) auto; 
  grid-template-columns: [one-January-2023] 0.97fr [two-January-2023] 0.97fr [three-January-2023] 0.97fr [four-January-2023] 0.97fr [five-January-2023] 0.97fr [six-January-2023] 0.97fr [seven-January-2023] 0.97fr [eight-January-2023] 0.97fr [nine-January-2023] 0.97fr [ten-January-2023] 0.97fr [eleven-January-2023] 0.97fr [twelve-January-2023] 0.97fr [thirteen-January-2023] 0.97fr [fourteen-January-2023] 0.97fr [fifteen-January-2023] 0.97fr [sixteen-January-2023] 0.97fr [seventeen-January-2023] 0.97fr [eighteen-January-2023] 0.97fr [nineteen-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-one-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-two-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-three-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-four-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-five-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-six-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-seven-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-eight-January-2023] 0.97fr [twenty-nine-January-2023] 0.97fr [thirty-January-2023] 0.97fr [thirty-one-January-2023] 0.97fr
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="grid-column-start: four-January-2023; grid-column-end: twenty-January-2023">
  <div style="grid-column-start: ten-January-2023; grid-column-end: twenty-eight-January-2023">
</div>
```

I would like to have each div inside container (that are rendered dinamically in a ngFor directive) disposed in subsequent row. How can I obtain this objective?

Answer (score 0):

To place two div elements in a single row within this grid, you can use the `grid-row` property to specify the same row for both divs:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="grid-column-start: four-January-2023; grid-column-end: twenty-January-2023" grid-row: 1;>
  <div style="grid-column-start: ten-January-2023; grid-column-end: twenty-eight-January-2023" grid-row: 1;>
</div>
```

In that way you can place `div` elements.

Comment: I would the opposite solution. A progressive grid-row. 1-2-3-4...etc. But automatically with css without this property.